# In Corda, improperly specified input name error when running the bootstrapper

Tags: corda

In Corda 3, when I run the node bootstrapper, I get the following error message:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: improperly specified input name: Vast Global MegaCorp, Ltd
          at javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal.<init>(X500Principal.java:183) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal.<init>(X500Principal.java:128) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name$Companion.parse(CordaX500Name.kt:114) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.config.ConfigUtilities.getSingleValue(ConfigUtilities.kt:81) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.config.ConfigUtilities.getValueInternal(ConfigUtilities.kt:64) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.config.ConfigUtilities.parseAs(ConfigUtilities.kt:49) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.node.services.config.NodeConfigurationKt.parseAsNodeConfiguration(NodeConfiguration.kt:330) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.node.CmdLineOptions.loadConfig(ArgsParser.kt:96) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.loadConfigFile(NodeStartup.kt:202) ~[corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:75) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
          at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect AVA format
          at sun.security.x509.AVA.readChar(AVA.java:555) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at sun.security.x509.AVA.<init>(AVA.java:181) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at sun.security.x509.AVA.<init>(AVA.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at sun.security.x509.RDN.<init>(RDN.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
          at sun.security.x509.X500Name.parseDN(X500Name.java:916) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3, commas are not allowed in node names. You can see the full list of constraints here: https://docs.corda.net/head/node-structure.html#node-naming.